# how to print output of a subroutine in C?

Tags: c, subroutine

I am using a very simple code for subroutine but it is not printing right values.
Please help me in this. My code is:

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

main(){
  int i, a, b=0.0, c=0.0;
  void sum(int a , int b);
  for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {   
    sum (a, b); c = c+b;
  }
  printf("%d\n", c);
}
void sum(int a , int b){
  int i;
  for ( i = 0; i <6; i++ )  {a = i*i;b = b+a;}
}
```

Comment: `sum (a, b)` is a [NOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP)

Comment: Also, stop using a 25+ year-old book that declares `main` with no return type, encourages the declaration of functions *within* functions, etc., etc...

Comment: here i am calling a function sum (a, b)that is the subroutine, therefore it should work.

Comment: thank you for your comment i will improve it.

Answer (score 2):

The effects of `sum(int,int)` are not visible to the caller, because `a` and `b` are passed by value. You need to use pointers to achieve the results that you want:

```
void sum(int *a , int *b){
    for (int i = 0; i <6; i++ ) {
        *a = i*i;
        *b += *a;
    }
}
```

Change the forward declaration to use pointers as well, and call `sum (&a, &b)` to pass the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`sum(a, b)` is a [NOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP), you need to pass a pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sum(int *a, int *b)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        *a = i * i;
        *b = *b + *a;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, a, b = 0.0, c = 0.0;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {   
        sum(&a, &b);
        c = c + b;
    }
    printf("%d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function by values. You should call the function by reference that is using pointers or reference.

Answer (score 0):

For adding in subroutines you need to use [Call by reference Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_reference.htm). Then only the values are properly assigned to variables. But you are using [Call by Value Method](http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-call-by-value-or-call-by-reference). so it will pass only the copy of the values to subroutine function. What are the changes made in subroutine that does not affect in main function. Try the following changes

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

main(){
int i, a, b=0, c=0; // fix 1
void sum(int *a , int *b); // fix 2
  for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {
  sum (&a, &b); c = c+b; // fix 3
  }
  printf("%d\n", c);
}
void sum(int *a , int *b){ // fix 4
  int i;
  for ( i = 0; i <6; i++ )  {*a = i*i;*b = *b+*a;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>


void sum(int *a , int *b);
int main() {
  int i, a, b=0.0, c=0.0;
  for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
  {
        sum (&a, &b);
        c = c+b;
  }
  printf("%d\n", c);
}

void sum(int *a , int *b){
  int i;
  for ( i = 0; i <6; i++ )
  {
        *a = i*i;
        *b = (*b) + (*a);
  }
  return;
}
```

**Output:**

```
165
```

I have done required formating of your code and changes function arguments to pointer type.